# Android textView marquee/banner that's constantly updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter, android-scrollview

I'm trying to put a marquee at the bottom of my app of status updates of different users of the app. It must constantly be moving to the left displaying each status one after the other. Users can continuously change update their status which gets stored in a database on a server so basically the marquee needs to be constantly checking for another update and add it to the text view and scroll through it, so the marquee can't just roll over when it's finished it must just display the next status. Is this possible to do?? using a scrollView or listView or something. It needs to scroll horizontally though. You don't have to show me how to parse the strings from the server or database or anything you can just use and arrayList or something.I just need to know how to constantly check for updates and then add it to the marquee without the marquee ever pausing or rolling over unless there are no new status updates.

If you could do this it would be a TREMENDOUS help and in my eyes i would consider you a genius of the free world. Thank you people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver & Service for doing this.

- Using alarmmanager you can check for updates after a particular time interval.
- Using BroadcastReceiver & Service you can set new update to your textview.

You just need to google for these things. These are enough to achieve that functionality.